# Are all lattices chains?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Are all lattices chains?
I think that is true because a chain is a poset where we can compare any two elements. A lattice is a poset where every subset has a lub and a gld. So, by reducing the size of the subset to two, having a lub and glb essentially means they are comparable and hence a chain. Is my intuition wrong?

Comment: See "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368136/example-of-a-lattice-that-isnt-a-chain"

Comment: A good example of a lattice is: the collection $\mathcal P(X)$ of all subsets of a set $X$, ordered by inclusion $\subseteq$.  Then use the definition of lub to prove: $A \cup B$ is the lub of $A$ and $B$.  And yet it could be that neither of $A,B$ is contained in the other.

Comment: Your argument only proves two things: that every chain is a lattice; and that every two element lattice is a chain. For the rest, I agree with the amusing answer J.-E. Pin gave.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same type of argument as in the following "proof".

> All points of the plane are aligned. Indeed, two points are aligned.
>   Take now $n+1$ points $a_0, \ldots, a_n$. By the induction hypothesis,
>   the $n$ points $a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ are aligned and so are $a_1,
>  \ldots, a_n$. Since there is only one line containing $a_1, a_2$, the
>   $n+1$ points are aligned.

Can you see the gap in this argument?